# How to get screen's physical size (i.e. in inches) in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing a Hybrid App using ionic and I'm new to this. Based on the physical width of the screen I want to show or hide my pages. I'm using platform.width() from ionic but I'm not sure if this value is in pixel. also if this is in pixels then how to convert that into inches? is there any other way by which I can get the physical width of the screen in inches?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the screen size using platform shows as pixels. To convert to inches, you need to do something like the following: [How to convert pixels to inch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972761/how-to-convert-pixels-to-inch)

Comment: if it's in pixel and I convert it into inches, will it remain the same for all resolutions?

Comment: it should ne the same for all, its being converted.